# Spring Boot REST Validation is different from packed JAR to IDE started application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm completly confused atm.
When I start my application from Intellij and run into a Validation error the correct error is thrown which you can see in postman:
[image: postman api request]

But when I do `mvn clean package` and start the application via jar file the error output is totally different:
[image]

Nevertheless the console throws the correct error:
[image]

Has anyone ever had such a strange problem?

Answer (score 2):

The difference might come from spring-boot-devtools. They are active, when started from within the IDE, but are missing from the jar.

Devtools enabled some more detailed error reportings.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.4.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-devtools/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/devtools/env/DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor.java for more information.

Comment: But the error messages are from my validation class there is no connection between my validation classes and the spring-starter-test dependency

Comment: It is the devtools dependency, not the spring-starter-test one. I assume the property in question being server.error.include-binding-errors

Comment: You are right! When I remove the devtools and start with ide, its the same error message like after mvn package... But how can i get the correct validation error output?

Comment: Just add the property server.error.include-binding-errors with value true in your application.properties/yaml